# In R, line slope changes when only x values as shifted

Tags: r, regression, computational-statistics, lm

I'm new to R, and trying out few examples in it.
I'm trying to find the slope of a plotted graph, using lm function.

My code:

```
Xvalues: int 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9..
Yvalues: int 202 247 296 336 376 479 553 756 861 957 ...
```

There are totally 38 values, x ending with 38, y with 4000.
So I did:

```
> fit<-lm(yval ~ xval)
> fit

Call:
lm(formula = yval ~ xval)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         xval  
     -118.2        106.6
```

So 106.6 is the slope m in y = mx + c,
but when I start my x values from say 201410 till 201448, I got this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = yval ~ xval)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         xval  
 -2.145e+07    1.066e+02
```

the value changes by 170, of course when I do arctan I get angle close to 90, that isn't an issue, but I'm trying to understand why is this large difference in slope, essentially it should be same with variation in Y-intercept c.

Can anyone explain how it calculates the values.
Any help would help me significantly.

Thank you.

Comment: Where does that "170" come from? Note that `106.6=1.066e+02` to the quoted accuracy. It is possible you're unfamiliar with the meaning of the "e+02" part. Can you clarify how you got 170?

Comment: Yes thank you, my bad, I interpreted in a different way,. thank you for the prompt response.

Comment: Should I expand on that a little as an answer?

Comment: That's fine I get it,. I was not familiar with the representation. Thank you. BTW, how do I mark it as solved?

Comment: You can't unless someone answers. Once you have an answer you can indicate you have an answer that solves your problem by clicking the grey check mark (turning it green). I'll write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I just noticed I never came back and answered this, sorry)

The problem appears to be that you're not familiar with how computers represent scientific notation.

In scientific notation, we could write $106.6$ as $1.066\times 10^{2}$. That's just two different ways of representing the same quantity. On a computer that's [usually shown as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) `1.066e+02`, so `106.6` = `1.066e+02` to the quoted accuracy.

Which is to say that the two slopes are actually the same.