# How does one interpret the last two symbols/letters "E4" in an arithmetic mean?

Tags: spss, notation

In SPPS, how does one interpret the last two symbols/letters 'E4' in an arithmetic mean? For example, mean monthly family income is shown as 3.79E4. What does E4 symbolise? How can we interpret it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: Questions about notation are on topic here. This question seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: Duplicates 1. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138856/what-does-8-6e-28-mean-in-the-result-from-a-white-test-testing-for-heteroscedast
2. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155163/what-does-the-number-e-mean
3. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161317/in-r-line-slope-changes-when-only-x-values-as-shifted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exponential form: $3.79E4=3.79 \times 10^4$

Comment: You can force Statistics not to use scientific notation for small values via Edit > Options > General  then check "No scientific notation ..."